# What is the symonym of the word dissing here?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What is the symonym of the word dissing here?

But be wary of simplistic, baby-out-with-the-bathwater answers.
 Achieving Inbox Zero is not about “dissing” email, or melodramatically
 declaring “email bankruptcy.”

According to different sources the word "dissing" means "To show disrespect to, often by insult or criticism". I wonder if there is any other, more appropriate meaning.

Comment: So are you asking for a clarification of the definition, and not a synonym? Your title contradicts your question.

Comment: Actually anything that helps to understand it better)

Comment: I'm not sure of what the context is or what "Inbox Zero" is, but I don't know any alternative definition of dissing other than criticizing or slandering.

Comment: The main idea of Inbox Zero technology is to keep the inbox empty. I though about "to not pay enough attention" but I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the symonym of the word dissing here?

Synonyms typically provide shades of meaning, so there may not be a single (*the*) canonical synonym.

The sentence you're asking about is

> Achieving Inbox Zero is not about “dissing” email, or melodramatically declaring “email bankruptcy.”

In this context, *Inbox Zero* looks like the goal of having no (i.e. *zero*) items remaining in your inbox, perhaps after each email session.

The two alternatives suggested are to haughtily *dismiss* email altogether or to say that you're just going to give up on the goal. In the first case (extrapolating from the word 'dissing'), if you don't use email, you have no items in your inbox. Actually, you have no email inbox at all. This is the case you're interested in.

> **Dismissing**
>   : to decide not to think about or consider (something or someone) - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss)

Comment: No, I'm afraid this is wrong.  If you go to the url that contains the quote, you'll find that the author says that he's not "dissing" email as a communications medium.  In fact, he thinks email is important.  "Dissing" here means disrespecting.  Part of his advice is to actually dismiss certain kinds of email (e.g., unessential newsletters).  As always, context is everything.

Comment: @deadrat I looked for the original quote but didn't find it. Could you link to it, please? As for dismiss vs disrespect, there's some overlap and I think the sense I took it (haughty dismissal - looking down one's nose at it) is in that area of overlap. I could have chosen a less bland dictionary entry, I suppose.

Comment: Sure: https://medium.com/forte-labs/one-touch-to-inbox-zero-a74cfa02e5bf#.8cqje2owk

Comment: @deadrat Thanks for the link. Quoting from there: '.... Achieving Inbox Zero is not about “dissing” email, or melodramatically declaring “email bankruptcy.” // My attitude is the opposite: EVERY. SINGLE. EMAIL. is important.' This agrees with my point that *dissing* in this context is to be *dismissive* about email. Was there something else you were referring to when you said, 'No, I'm afraid this is wrong.'?

Comment: If you read the whole site (and I couldn't blame you if you didn't), the technique to get to the point where EVERY. SINGLE. EMAIL is important is that you indeed have to be dismissive of and actually dismiss certain kinds of email, which leaves *dissing* with its standard slang usage of disrespecting.

Comment: @deadrat Dismissing certain kinds of email isn't the same as being dismissive *about* email in general. It's the latter I meant, and I think that's consistent with the original. By analogy, dismissing certain types of EL&U questions isn't the same as dismissing EL&U altogether.

Comment: I'm going to bow out of this conversation as I'm in danger of turning into That Internet Guy Who Has to Have the Last Word on Everything.  And I hate that guy.